# Why isn't there a contract-to-hire option for job postings?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Long story short, I spent about 6 hours interviewing for a company between tech interviews and interviews with the team and the executive staff and it was a waste of time for everyone involved.

Everything had gone great so far in the interview process. It came down to the final interview with the President of the company. Right at the end of the conversation the President said "so hopefully this has been mentioned already, but this position will be contract-to-hire" and gave me their reasoning for that.

Without delving into my reasoning, simply put I am not willing to accept a contract-to-hire position.

Hindsight is 20/20 and I should have asked if it was a full-time *direct hire* position early on, but I assumed that since the Stack Overflow jobs posting said that it was "full-time" that it was indeed a full-time *direct hire* position **not** full-time *contract-to-hire*.

I not only wasted 6 hours of my time, but also a lot more than 6 hours of time at the company I interviewed at since every interview had a minimum of three people there. After I was told that it was contract-to-hire I basically said sorry for wasting everyone's time and went my separate way.

Here are the options I can filter by on Stack Overflow jobs. I would propose to add a "contract-to-hire" option or *some* way to distinguish between direct hire jobs and those which are not.

[image: Job Type currently only lists full time, contract, and internship as options.]

Comment: Type should be Permanent/Contract/Internship/Volunteer. Then there should be another separate filter for Full-time/Part-time/Casual

Comment: Frankly, this is a huge screwup on the employer's part, not yours.  The HR person should have asked this in the initial screen.  More options/clarity on SO would be helpful, but whoever posted the job still may/would have gotten it wrong.  And I'm not sure the contract vs full-time distinction is as relevant outside the US.

Comment: That sounds like borderline bait and switch on the part of the employer, honestly, though maybe they didn't intend it and it was an honest miscommunication (it's hard to tell sometimes, and I have seen companies try and attach strings at the last minute when they know you're pretty much committed); I'd consider that behavior a little suspicious. Even if it's not possible to filter on that, they should have put it *somewhere* in the job ad. I'm pretty sure SO jobs lets them type freeform text.

Comment: @SamuelLiew: "Contract to Hire" sounds like a reasonable option to have.  It is more or less an "industry-standard" term; everyone recognizes it, and it's used all the time in recruiter emails.

Comment: Mind you, I have no idea how "contract to hire" works, since I've never responded to any such job openings.  I've always assumed that it's a lengthy probation period, often accompanied by a relocation if it works out.  Is "must be willing to relocate" one of the options?

Comment: I think "Full-time" is an incorrect term as used on this page.  "Full-time" says to me how much I'll be working each day, and how many days (8ish and 5, respectively).  "Contract", "Internship" or "SALARY" tells me how I'll be paid and what I'm being promised besides.  I don't see "Full-time" turning out to be a contract or contract-to-hire being misleading.  I agree that if it took the final interview for the candidate to learn the full nature of the hire, that's very suspicious.  Anyway, my short answer here is that the quick fix I'd suggest is change "Full-time" to "Salary".

Comment: The specific wording 'contract to hire' is US centric I believe. Certainly in Australia just 'contract' is used for fixed term jobs, usually with an hourly or daily rate.

Comment: @Steve You can be a full-time employee and still be hourly. (Not as common for tech jobs but it happens.) Also, there's paid and unpaid internships so that term by itself doesn't tell you anything about pay.

Comment: @BSMP - Neither of your statements is incompatible with what I said.  In fact, the first, about full-time, is pretty much what I said.  I said that all full-time conveys is how much you'll be working, NOT how you'll be paid.  A paid vs unpaid internship also doesn't address how you'll be paid, but how much.  Of course, if you're paid zero, who's "paying" that becomes somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: I had a similar experience. They were SHOCKED when I wanted contractor rates for the contract side of the contract-to-hire.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I wouldn't quite put it that way, because normally people think of "probationary period" as a time when just the employer is making the decision.  Contract-to-hire is definitely much more a two-way street, where both parties are free to back out at any time.

Comment: @JamesMoore: In an "employment at will" state (like California, Texas and many others), those conditions already exist anyway.  If anything, contract work is *more* binding on both parties, not less.  But I do agree with others that the term "contract to hire" is probably US-centric.

Comment: @Steve I'm not understanding your suggestion to change full-time to salary in the options as a quick fix.

Comment: No amount of hand-wringing and semantics wrestling matters if the job poster mis-tags the job; I ignore all of the flags set on job listings, with the assumption the job poster and/or job site hasn't provided an accurate set of tags, I then ask explicitly on the first contact the type of job, eg, '*is this a contract and if so can it be filled on a corp-to-corp contract basis*', etc.; for the OP I'd mark this up as a (hard) lesson learned and in the future make sure these kinds of details are verified during the initial contact

Comment: Complete bait and switch. They may not even have that position open as such but may be trying out candidates. I have seen this in startups also, where they are going to be bought and they have to have X number of A list candidates to show to the board. Also, I am seeing too many fake recruiter profiles on LinkedIn, with the job market tumbling, we might see more of this.

Comment: @markp-fuso That's a good point. I think LinkedIn defaults their experience field to "entry level" because they have loads of Senior, Staff, Lead, Principal, VP, and even CEO positions labeled as being entry level jobs. And every job site I've used has had someone mark a job located in Washington, D.C as being in Washington state (and vice-versa).

Comment: It was closed down primo 2022: *[Sunsetting Jobs & Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story)*. The CEO in [the 2022-10-25](https://www.theverge.com/23421320/stack-overflow-ceo-interview-prashanth-chandrasekar-software-engineering-microsoft) *[The Verge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Verge)* article: *"When I joined the company, we were really sort of accelerating our SaaS business both in 2019, 2020. We pivoted away from that old talent, job listings business that I mentioned earlier, as we actually closed that business."* -

Comment: cont' - *"That was one of the tougher decisions in the company that I made. ... Then the Teams business really accelerated. That business now has every possible bank on the platform, every tech company that you can imagine, big retail companies, Microsoft, you name it. With all these 15,000 organizations..."*

Answer (score 27):

Note: The answer below is US-centric (most employment is at-will, meaning jobs that aren't time-limited don't normally have employment contracts) and assumed OP was in the US looking for a position in the US.

---

Taking a quick look at LinkedIn, Indeed, and Dice, they all have the following options for Job Type:

- Full-time
- Part-time
- Contract

and then depending on which site you're on, you'll also see Internship, Volunteer, Temporary, etc.

The implication is that both Full-time and Part-time jobs are permanent positions. This makes sense, since it isn't necessarily solely up to the employer whether a contractor works full-time or not.

Given the options on other job sites, I'd argue that this is entirely the employer's fault. I don't think it's reasonable to label a job that's definitely a contract position but will only *maybe* become permanent full-time as a full-time job. (This isn't to assume it was malicious but I don't think any blame belongs to the OP or SO.)

All that said, I think it could be useful for contract-to-hire to be its own job type option because this problem can also happen the other way: someone who's only looking to work on a contract basis going through an interview only to find out later that the company assumes that whoever gets the position will become full-time after the contract period.

Comment: Surely permanent positions normally have contracts too, and full-time positions can be time-limited (example full time 2 year project)?  The options "full-time / part-time" and "permanent / fixed-term" would seem orthogonal.  Perhaps fixed term are unusual in US businesses because anyone can be fired at will anyway?

Comment: *Surely permanent positions normally have contracts too...* @gerrit OK, I've spent enough time on The Workplace to have not made this mistake but I did it anyway. But yes, this answer is US-centric, where any time-limited position would be considered a contract job. Permanent positions don't normally have employment contracts in the US because most jobs are at-will.

Comment: @gerrit The terms are arbitrary and don't have much of a connection to their plain-language meaning any more.  Yes, every single job is going to have a contract, so you're right to think it's weird that there's a distinction between "contract" and "full-time".  And I don't think anyone in the US ever uses the term "fixed-term."  You'd just say "six month contract", which actually means something that can last up to six months, but is trivial for anyone to shorten (easy for either side) or lengthen (given agreement on both sides).